# Report SSRS server configuration error from local system

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am not able to configure the SSRS Report server.

I have tried with IE site setting . I am not finding site setting for change the security levels in report server . Actual you will find this my screen shot.

I needed to configure or use local SSRS server from my PC[image]

Currently i am getting like this in screen.
[image: I am getting this now.]

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your Reportserver with the **Reporting Services Configuration Manager**.
Should be installed on every Reportserver, there you can give yourself the needed permissions.

Comment: i am getting like this now it-rajesh/ReportServer_SQLTEST - /

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 12.0.4100.1

Comment: Hey @RajEsh you can change in the Reporting Services Congiguration Manager with the Menu Web Service URL the Virtual Directory. As a better way I would recommed you to use an IP-Address.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Error, It clearly states that you do not posses rights to view/update Reports.
You must first have proper rights and then it shall work.

Comment: Reporting Services Configuration Manager

Comment: I am getting like  this in IE screen                                                                      
  it-rajesh/ReportServer_SQLTEST - /

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 12.0.4100.1